# ruby how can i have the output give me the response as I would like it as below?

Tags: ruby

I would like the chat bot to respond with "Yes." If it ends the sentence with a period.
I would like the chat bot to respond with "Stop yelling." If it ends the sentence with an exclamation point.
If it ends with question mark, then I want the bot to say "Sure."

Comment: You will need to give more information about your problem someone to take time to help you. A current code sample of what you're trying to do, for example.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to check the end of strings for particular text, you may want to try the `ends_with?` [method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F).

```rb
input = "Here is a sentence."

input.ends_with? "." # true
input.ends_with? "!" # false
```